Creating a huge number of atomic struct
How would one go about designing a C++ program that may create over 100 million atomic structs? I would like to ensure that each of this atomic struct won't be written by two different threads. Each of these struct needs to persist throughout the program (since they may be modified in the future), but most likely they will only be used for a second.
In the cppreference atomic_flag documentation, one should not be using spin-locks.
Yet in a linux program, I don't think it is possible for the operating system to manage that many mutexes at once, despite pthread_mutex_init indicating that there is no limit.
Questions:

Is it a good idea to have an atomic_flag in each of the struct, and have an RAII wrapper that grabs the atomic_flag?
Is there any alternative solution that I should consider (eg using a mutex instead of an atomic_flag)?

My existing code:
struct S { int a; int b; .... int z; }; // assume there is 26 int fields
std::vector<S> v; // may contain > 100m objects

S getObject(size_t index) { return v[index]; }
int getSum(S s) { return a + b + ... + z; } // eg of a function i need
int update(S s, T t) {s.k = t.something; s.p = t.something_else;} // there can be multiple writers, upon each update, set a subset of fields in S to what another struct T contains

Some notes:

assume that upon every update, as long as the update was done atomically, the object will be in a valid state.
let me know if there are any other information that I should provide, but did not.
there is multiple update function that will update different multiple fields in the same code block
since someone asked, to be clear, there are multiple threads acting on each of these structs, hence i need some kind of synchronization.
I'm still in the designing phase, so I don't have any reproduce-able code.


I don't understand why you want atomic variables while your operations on them are not atomic

"// assume there is 26 int fields" std::array<int, 26>?


I don't understand why you want atomic variables while your operations on them are not atomic

Multiple threads will be acting on each struct.

// assume there is 26 int fields" std::array<int, 26>
there are double and char too, but I'm trying to simplify the information. Specifically I don't want a magical lock on the array to make this work.


You could always divide up the array into N different subsets, and protect each subset with its own mutex.  Each thread would lock only the appropriate mutex for the subset containing the entry it wants to interact with, and you could choose N appropriately so that it's large enough to minimize lock contention but small enough to be practical.  (if you're going to be holding multiple locks at once, be sure to enforce a consistent locking order to avoid deadlocks!)

On linux mutex is implemented via futex which consumes no kernel resources when no threads are blocked on it. It's fine to have millions of them.

@weineng -- vector of atomic variables does not provide atomic operations, it creates copies, it moves, etc.

A mutex does not consume OS resources, only waiting on it does (and that scales with the number of threads, not number of mutexes). 26 integer fields is large enough that a mutex per struct sounds reasonable. But you cannot put a mutex into a vector since vector needs to move its data on size changes. A deque works fine though, provided you don't also want to dynamically add and remove items. Then you probably also need a shared_mutex for the deque as a whole. Or if the size is fixed on init, unique_ptr<S[]> (the array specialization) also works well with no overhead compared to vector

If you want a good solution, you need to think about your access patterns. How many accesses are read-only, and how many are mutating? Is starvation a problem? Is forward progress required? Do the threads access objects in a predictable way?

I don't like the wording of "is it a good idea to...".  It makes it harder to seek an objective answer.  It's your program.  You get to decide what's good or bad about it.

If you are still in the designing phase, I would suggest you do a proof-of-concept (PoC) first to test the tools you are going to use. That is where you can check the statement that pthread_mutex_init indicating that there is no limit.
Once PoC is ready you can benchmark it with perf.
Regarding the std::mutex. In case if you are sure your threads are not going to lock the objects for a long time and there will be no contentions, I would use SpinLock (the implementation you can find in Internet). The main reason is that std::mutex object itself consumes 40 bytes or so, while SpinLock can be implemented using the regular atomic_bool/atomic_flag.
Another point, in case if you are going to have multiple threads modifying the entries in the array, I would suggest to have the structures aligned at CPU cache line boundary. That will save you from false sharing. The drawback is padding. If you say that your structure contains 26 ints, then the padding is 26 * sizeof(int) = 104; (64 * 2) - 104 = 24 bytes.
constexpr auto CpuCacheLineSize = 64;

struct alignas(CpuCacheLineSize) S
{
};

If you are curious about right memory layout you may want to read the nice article by Ulrich Drepper "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory"
So, to answer your question:

A1: std::atomic_flag alone may cause the performance degradation. In addition to std::atomic_flag you may need to call std::thread::yield(). Also the performance of the locking function may depend on how do you write the atomic value. I won't suggest to use std::atomic_flag. instead find the existent implementation of the SpinLock.
A2: It is hard to suggest which class is better for the synchronization. Either to SpinLock or std::mutex depends on how do you design your application. You do not want to have threads struggling for the lock. In the best case they should run in the isolated environment and do not modify the shared memory. Then it does not really matter what do you use. If I were you, I'd start with std::mutex. Once app is ready, then measure the performance. Then change the mutex with SpinLock and measure the performance again. Then decide.

